# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column

Tags: pyspark

Am I doing this right?
I have a time stamp column that I convert into a first of the month date.

```
df= df.withColumn("monthlyTransactionDate", f.trunc(df[transactionDate], 'mon').alias('month'))
```

I then run this code as I want to generate all possible months between the min and max dates:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

minDate, maxDate = df.select(f.min("MonthlyTransactionDate"), f.max("MonthlyTransactionDate")).first()


df.withColumn("monthsDiff", f.months_between(maxDate, minDate))\
    .withColumn("repeat", f.expr("split(repeat(',', monthsDiff), ',')"))\
    .select("*", f.posexplode("repeat").alias("date", "val"))\
    .withColumn("date", f.expr("add_months(minDate, date)"))\
    .select('date')\
    .show(n=50)
```

But get the error on the start of the last section:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 2016-12-01 of type <type 'datetime.date'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,

```
 minDate, maxDate = df.select(f.min("MonthlyTransactionDate"), f.max("MonthlyTransactionDate")).first()
```

returns min and max date value of date format.To use exact values for all rows,use `lit() from functions`

```
 df.withColumn("monthsDiff", f.months_between(f.lit(maxDate), f.lit(minDate)))
```

Comment: Thanks that's given me another error: AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`minDate`' given input columns: (follwowed by all the fields in my df). Will see if I can resolve it.

Comment: I think, the error is from ,`withColumn("date", f.expr("add_months(minDate, date)"))`

Comment: I ended up using Pandas to do this then converting to Spark